# Getting Invalid number of parameters in Doctrine2 and Symfony Querybuilder

Tags: orm, symfony, doctrine-orm

Here is my code

```
if(!$criteria){
            return null;
        }

        $em = $this->doctrine->getEntityManagerForClass('Sample\MyBundle\Entity\Call');
        $qb = $em->createQueryBuilder();
        $qb->add('select', 'c')->add('from', 'Sample\MyBundle\Entity\Call c');

        if($criteria->getReason() && $criteria->getReason() != null){
            $qb->add('where', 'c.reason = ?1');
            $qb->setParameter(1, $criteria->getReason());
        }
        if($criteria->getCallDate() && $criteria->getCallDate() != null){
            $qb->add('where', 'c.callTime = ?2');
            $qb->setParameter(2, $criteria->getCallDate());
        }

        if($criteria->getPage()>1){
            $qb->setFirstResult(($criteria->getPage()-1) * 10)->setMaxResults(10);
        }

        $query = $qb->getQuery();
        return $query->getResult();
```

I'm getting this error - `Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens` I googled but couldn't found a solution. Need help with this.

I even tried to put both setParameter() calls after conditional check if statements but that also give the same error. If I don't set the second parameter and remove second where condition then it works.

Comment: Have you tried it without the "c" alias (remove the alias altogether as it's not needed)? Call directly 'reason = ?1' Btw it's an sql error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, I guess I was making a mistake. I think I can not use multiple 'where' in 'add' function. I replaced it with `$qb->andWhere('c.callTime > ?2');` and now it works fine.